# Using sample() in R in a conditional way

Tags: r, random, sample

I want to assign a random number of B for each number of A.
The condition is that the numer assigned of B must be bigger than the corresponding number of A.
Here is my code.
Is there any way to do this faster?
I tried with the for loop and other ways with a worst result!
Thanks a lot!

```
set.seed(123)
A <- rlnorm(10000,5,1) 
B <- rlnorm(100000,10,2)
df <- data.frame(NumPol=1:length(B), Cap=B)

pol_sel <- sapply(1:length(A), FUN = function(i) { 
sample(df$NumPol[which(df$Cap > A[i])], size=1, replace=TRUE) } )
```

Comment: not sure I completely understand this. A and B are different sizes, what do you mean that the "number of B must be bigger than the corresponding number of A"?

Comment: Why not just randomly choose a positive number to add to A to get B?

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yes, A and B have different sizes. B is bigger. For each value of A I want to find a random number of B that must be bigger than this corresponding value of A.

Comment: What is the purpose of variable `NumPol`?

Comment: variable NumPol is just to get the position of the values of B returned. Tanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but maybe you want something similar to this:

```
set.seed(123)
A <- sample(10000, 10000)

rnd.sample <- function(x) {
  i <- 1
  B <- c()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    success <- FALSE
    while(success == FALSE) {
      s <- sample(100000, 1)
      if (s > x[i]) {
        success <- TRUE
        B[i] <- s
        i <- i + 1
      } else {}
    }
  }
  return(data.frame(A = x, B))
}

head(rnd.sample(A), 10)
#       A     B
# 1  2876 31060
# 2  7883 32453
# 3  4089 87026
# 4  8828 32868
# 5  9401 12571
# 6   456 35623
# 7  5278 93070
# 8  8918 87518
# 9  5510 82022
# 10 4563 63124
```

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not wath I need. Imagine that in A, there are 10.000 claim amounts. In B, there are 100.000 insurance policies with the aomunt of risk insured for each one. I want to assign each claim to a policy randomnly. But the condition is that the capital insured must be bigger than the claim.

Comment: Updated my answer again, please check.

Answer (score 0):

For each element `a` in A, sampling one instance from the elements in B which are larger than `a` would be given by:

```
sapply(A, function(a) sample(B[B > a], size = 1, replace = TRUE))
```

If it's not fast enough, you can use [mclapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mclapply.html) instead of `sapply` to parallelize (which should be fine, since you're using `replace = TRUE` and the samplings are independent).